# Why regionprops function is undefined in my installation of Matlab 2011a?

Tags: matlab, computer-vision

I am using Matlab 2011a on windows 8, and I am trying to run a code that uses `regionprops` fucntion. This function is undefined and  in Matlab 2011 there is no help on it while in R2016a, help says that it is introduced before R2006a.

Comment: `regionprops` is a part of the image processing toolbox, what does `license('test', 'image_toolbox')` says in your machine?

Comment: `license('test', 'image_toolbox')

ans = 1`

Comment: and `which regionprops`?

Comment: with no input: `regionprops -
??? Undefined function or variable 'regionprops'.`
with input: `stats = regionprops(seg, 'PixelIdxList', 'Area');
??? Undefined function or method 'regionprops' for input arguments of type 'double'.`

Comment: It should work according to the [R2011a documentation](http://nl.mathworks.com/help/releases/R2011a/toolbox/images/). Are you able to use other function of this toolbox?

Answer (score 1):

`regionprops` is part of Image Processing Toolbox. You probably don't have that product installed.